# Python subprocess.communicate stderrdata not printing

Tags: python, subprocess, stderr

I'm changing all *getstatusoutput* usage to *subprocess* in a python script.  Both methods return stdout and stderr.  stdout is consistent for both.  But, whereas stderr is 0 for getstatusoutput,  it is blank for subprocess.communicate.

The getstatusoutput code:

> ```
> cmd = "openssl verify -CAfile {} {}".format(root_cert, subca_cert)
> status, out = commands.getstatusoutput(cmd)
> LOG(OKGREEN, "out={}".format(out))
> LOG(OKGREEN, "status={}".format(status))
> ```

Prints what I expect:

> ```
> out=sub_ca.cer: OK 
> status=0
> ```

But the subprocess code:

> ```
> cmd = ['openssl', 'verify', '-CAfile', root_cert, subca_cert]
> p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)
> (out,status) = p.communicate()
> LOG(OKGREEN, "out={}".format(out))
> LOG(OKGREEN, "status={}".format(status))
> ```

Prints this:

> ```
> out=innerspace.cer: OK
>
> status=
> ```

There’s an extra line feed and stderr is blank. Can you spot what I’m doing wrong?
For reference: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects

Comment: The results from `commands.getstatusoutput()` aren't stdout/stderr, they are stdout/process exit code.  If you want the exit code from the `subprocess` version, look at `p.returncode`.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use if you're going to be using `Popen` is `Popen.returncode`.

That's because there is no status from `stderr`. Your `status` variable is a `None` object until the process raises some error, in which then `stderr` will write to that `status` variable you have. If there are no errors, it will then remain a `None` and thus not print anything. I've updated your code with the changes.

```
cmd = ['openssl', 'verify', '-CAfile', root_cert, subca_cert]
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)
out, errors = p.communicate()
LOG(OKGREEN, "out={}".format(out))
LOG(OKGREEN, "status={}".format(p.returncode))
```